# Theorem 5.1.4 from High-Dimensional Probability - Concentration on the Sphere

Tags: probability

Let $M$ denote the median of a Lipschitz function $f(X)$ with Lipschitz norm equal to 1. How can I show that if $\left \| f(X)-M \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq C $, then $\left \| f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq C$?

I understand that $\left \| \mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq K\left | \mathbb{E}f(X) \right |\leq\mathbb{E}\left | f(X) \right |=\left \| f(X) \right \|_{L_{1}}$. But the median M is the minimizer for the $L_{1}$, does it suffice to prove the result?

Comment: Please don't just post a new question, but [edit the original one to improve it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/637743/1352). (And please do answer whuber's questions there.) The moderators can help you merge your accounts if required.

Comment: What would the median of a *function* be??  BTW, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts: that will help you edit anything you have posted.